# windows search service is corrupted (indexing location button grayed out)

Tags: search, service, windows-10, regedit

first it was a driver index issue even when i click show all location,
[driver cannot be found in indexed location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnk9p.png)

i tried to select new index location to be on the drive that was missing then the index service collapsed and did not run at all giving me an error when go to services and try running it manually:

```
Windows could not start the Windows Search service on Local Computer Error 21:  The device is not ready
```

and the select new location button grayed out, [select new button grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFfAa.png)

then i delete the Key RebuildIndex and change value of key SetupCompletedSuccessfully to 1 in the registry edit as mention in one article, https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/36379-windows-search-indexing-broken.html and started to get another error when trying to run windows search service
[Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyhok.png)

any idea how to solve this issue?

windows details:
windows 10 Home - version 1909 - OS build 18363.752